# JFrame getContentPane.removeAll() only working between a .setVisible(false) and .setVisible(true)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The folloing code is supposed to reset the frame gameFrame:

```
private void reset()
{
    moveCount = 0;
    gameFrame.setVisible(false);

    gameFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    gameFrame.getContentPane().revalidate();
    gameFrame.getContentPane().repaint();

    board.newBoard();
    createGameUI(board.getWidth(),board.getHeight());

    gameFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

However it only works by first setting visibility of gameFrame to false, removing all components, adding a fresh set of components, and then setting the gameFrame to visible.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks,

Oli

EDIT:

I've tried doing:

```
private void reset()
{
    moveCount = 0;

    //gameFrame.setVisible(false);
    gameFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();

    createGameUI(board.getWidth(),board.getHeight());

    gameFrame.getContentPane().revalidate();
    gameFrame.getContentPane().repaint();
    //gameFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

However this now just freezes the program when I press the reset button.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 7):

A better approach is to have a reset method that resets the state of all the components in your game instead of recreating all the components.

However the general rule for removing/adding components to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Your code doesn't do the revalidate() and repaint() AFTER you add all the new components to the content pane of the frame.

Comment: I tried putting the .revalidate and .repaint below adding to the frame but this now freezes when calling the reset function. Any ideas?

Comment: @OliBates are you calling your `reset()` method inside a `paint`? Did you check if a CPU is using 100%?